# Pass PowerShell arguments to Process.Start

Tags: c#, powershell, command-line-arguments

I am trying to convert some of my bat scripts over to C#. 
I have the entire program ported except for the PowerShell execution line.

To keep things simple, I was trying to just call the PowerShell command from cmd.
I am able to do so but its not taking the complex arguments and parameters that go along with the PowerShell command.

Here is the command if I run directly from cmd or bat file.

```
powershell -Command "& {asnp 'citrix*'; remove-BrokerTag -Name 'Somename' -Machine 'domain\server' -AdminAddress 'SomeServer';}"
```

I was using this code to invoke cmd and run my powershell command.

```
string strCmdText;
strCmdText = "'/C powershell " + "-Command " + "&" + " { asnp 'citrix*'; add - BrokerTag - Name 'Somename' - Machine 'domain\server'" + (listboxvariable) + " - AdminAddress 'ServerXX'; }'" + " & pause";
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("CMD.exe", strCmdText);
```

I get this error
*"Cannot process the command because of a missing parameter. A command must follow -Command."*

As you can see there are a lot of arguments in this PowerShell command.

Is there an easier way to do this? or I am just missing something simple?

Comment: If already converting the code to C#, why not using C# classes to preform the same action? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.powershell?view=powershellsdk-1.1.0 Goodluck!

Answer (score 4):

In your original PowerShell line, the `Command` is surrounded by double quotes.

Try this:

```
strCmdText = "/C powershell " + "-Command " + "\"& " + "{ asnp 'citrix*'; add - BrokerTag - Name 'Somename' - Machine 'domain\server'" + (listboxvariable) + " - AdminAddress 'ServerXX'; }\"" + " & pause";
```

Notice the use of `\"` escape sequences to add the missing double quotes that are present in your original command line.

Comment: i get the same error.  --> Cannot process the command because of a missing parameter. A command must follow -Command. Followed by  --> '"{ asnp 'citrix*'; add - BrokerTag - Name 'somename' - Machine 'domain'server - AdminAddress 'Server'; }"' is not recognized as an internal or external command,

Comment: @Robert Harvey♦ The original `Command` has a double quote before the `&` shouldn't the `\"` be inserted before the `&` instead of putting it after ?

Comment: @pnadalini: Fixed.

Comment: thanks!! .. the powershell command is actually running now.. but now a problem when trying to define the -Machine parameter. it seems to be ignoring the \ in domain\machine..

Comment: I guess you will have to double the backslash there too: `domain\\server`

Comment: thanks guys.. its working now.. the single line powershell command is what was giving me so many problems now.. i basically had to add a + for every powershell parameter in the line.. thank you all for the help!